# Spring framework Servlet hiding regular Java HttpServlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I am developing a Java application that is to have two web interfaces: a servlet handling some web service logic (/WSProxy) and a web admin interface using the Spring framework (/Admin or *.html). My problem is that the Spring framework dispatcher is hiding the other Servlet; I can view the logs and see that my Admin Servlet is loaded in the server log but every time I try to navigate to it in my browser, it appears as though the Sping Servlet is trying to handle the request! Thanks.

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RicochetAdmin</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RicochetProxy</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>WSProxy.Servlets.RicochetProxy</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>ricochet.xml.path</param-name>
            <param-value>C:\Users\cdix\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Ricochet\web\WEB-INF\conf\ricochet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RicochetProxy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/RicochetProxy/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/RicochetProxy</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RicochetAdmin</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Why don't you post your web.xml? You need to configure your url mapping.

Comment: OK, now what requests are being "hidden"? What's the URL you're trying?

Comment: For example: if I wanted to retrieve a WSDL file from the RicochetProxy, I would want to navigate to /RicochetProxy/name-of-wsdl?WSDL however I get a "resource not found" page (I know the WSDL i "there" and don't get any error messages from the server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Ricochet is your app (war) name, you'd need to change the second mapping from *.html to /RicochetAdmin/*.html. The way you have it now the Spring dispatcher is being called for every request ending with .html.

Answer (score 0):

Change ordering of your servlet mappings in `web.xml` so that Spring's dispatcher is loaded after your other servlet.

Comment: I do think that my servlet mappings are overlapping however I am having some difficulty making it work. I am relatively new to Java development and am getting my feet wet. If the project name is Ricochet, I used to be able to get to RicochetProxy by going to /Ricochet/RicochetProxy. If I change the mappings to /Ricochet/RicochetProxy and /Ricochet/RicochetAdmin, I get a resource not found message. Am I on the right track?